# Battery Charging log

Tags: windows-8, performance-analysis, battery

Can someone please recommend a software for Windows 8 laptop, that can show vital battery stats like:

- discharge rate
- charging cycle
- health
- most importantly, charging time and discharging time

Is there an app that can do this?

Comment: Where do you want the stats shown?

Comment: @Undo: I believe this is a secondary problem. These aren't stats that necessarily need to be viewed "live".

Comment: Agreed with Undo. But I will love to see it on my taskbar, near the clock maybe.